# Utilize data.table's binary search capabilities in subset based on inequalities

Tags: r, data.table

I'd like to take advantage of data.table's fast binary search capabilities to subset a data.table in two ways. First, I'd like to eliminate just one set of values from the original data table. Second, I'd like to keep only records satisfying an inequality criteria. For (a very simplified) example, say you had the following:

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(letter = rep(c('',letters[1:4]), each = 4),
                 date = as.IDate(c('2014-09-29','2014-09-30','2014-10-01','2014-10-02')))
```

In the results, I want a data.table that excludes entries in which letter is blank, and for which the date is earlier than October, 1 2014. In this case:

```
   letter       date
1:      a 2014-09-29
2:      a 2014-09-30
3:      b 2014-09-29
4:      b 2014-09-30
5:      c 2014-09-29
6:      c 2014-09-30
7:      d 2014-09-29
8:      d 2014-09-30
```

I know there are a plethora of ways to satisfy this using a wide variety of packages, and the (old?) approach in data.table would be something along the lines of:

```
dt[letter != '' & date < '2014-10-01',]
```

However, I don't believe this uses the fast binary search capabilities. Unfortunately, speed and generalizability are essential here, as the data sets with which I'm working generally have 300 million or more rows, the panels are unbalanced, and the cutoff dates change. I realize several similar questions have been asked and answered, but none that seem to address the subset (i.e., not join) issue since non-equi joins were released in data.table v1.9.7. My hope is that this new feature allows for non-equi subsets as well.

--Edit--

Thank you for the helpful comments so far. My question is, "Is there a way to create this subset that would utilize data.table's binary search capabilities?"

Comment: ...so what is your _question_?

Comment: No, but it's filed if I'm reading this correctly: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1801 Like jmoon said, this doesn't look like a real programming question yet. In particular, if you want to ask a question about performance, it should scale up as a function of `n` or something and should include things like "the cutoff dates change" (per letter?) as part of it.

Comment: Not sure if `sqldf` will enhance performance here. Just a thought.